# Is the Google I/O 2010 Android app open source?

Tags: android

The Google I/O app was made by Google to help attendees to the conference track which sessions they want to watch and see the entire schedule. I was wondering if it was available as open source since it has some good UI design and usability patterns.

Comment: Sounds interresting, is there a link to where I can see the app?

Comment: Jonas: Just search the Market. Or see package com.google.android.apps.iosched

Comment: Hopefully they'll open source the application after Google IO is finished; I can't see any reason why they couldn't do so.

Comment: I talked with one of the Android devs today at Google I/O and he said he will put the app on Google Code soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently as of today they have not put the code out there yet, but here's where I found it will potentially reside:

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Comment: now let's hope the Twitter Android app will be open sourced as well

Comment: hey does anyone know when / if the Android app will be open sourced?

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for it, but I couldn't find it.

Twitter app is also very similar and it will be opensource, so I guess we'll have to wait.

Comment: Indeed, they highlighted many of the UI patterns of that app on their blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping the Google I/O 2010 app would be released as open source for exactly the reasons stated in the question.

The Google I/O 2009 was released as open source and proved very useful, examining the code as a learning exercise.

I would imagine the code will probably appear at:

http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Android

The recent release of the Google My Tracks app lives at code.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

The best indication of their open source code is usually the presence of it on Google Code.

A few quick searches revealed nothing on there, so it isn't there now.

It's also unlikely to appear since it's such a small program and they only usually open the source to applications they intend development to continue for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that http://code.google.com/p/iosched/  has been updated with recent 2012 app code, the older 2011 code is still relevant if you are working on 2.3 et al and can be found at https://github.com/jwang/iosched

Answer (score 0):

I just released ported version for Eclipse IoSched 2013 in here :

https://github.com/yodiaditya/iosched-2013-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The official Google I/O 2017 conference app was the co-pilot to navigate the conference, whether you're attending in-person or remotely. With the app, you can:

- Explore the conference schedule, with details on topics and speakers
- Save events to My I/O, your personalized schedule
- Get reminders before events you’ve saved in My I/O start.

Google I/O 2017 app's source code released on GitHub to demonstrate the newest, best practices for Android devs.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is Open Source because

- Google Android Apps are usually not open source (Gmail, GMaps, Youtube etc... are not part of the Android OS, but are proprietary apps)
- There was no anoucement it was going to be Open Source.

I might be wrong though.